# using css in NextJS components without importing it as an object

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js, styled-components

I want to accomplish something like this

Button.module.css

```
.error {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

button.js

```
import './Button.module.css'

export function Button() {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className="error"
    >
      Destroy
    </button>
  )
}
```

I know that I can import css like `import styles from './Button.module.css'`
as an object and access `{styles.error}` from it, but since my team has separate people who do the styling (HTML/CSS), it would be a pain for them to write it this way, plus I guess you'd also have to camel case the classes.

Comment: You can import all styles as global ones into `_app.js`. But! This is super-bad approach since you have to use unique class-names. More than that all ``css`` styles will load together which is bad.

Comment: Once you are using css in javascript, you have to import it as an object! Even if you include all your styling on the same file of your component, you will have to do it as an object.

Comment: You'll have to do `import styles from './Button.module.css'` then `className={styles.error}`.